# Displaying an image in full width that you can scroll up and down

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjiPU.jpg in a webpage in full without it being zoomed in. I've tried many ways of doing it it's always either cut or too zoomed in. Here's my current result https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPFo3.jpg with this image being scrollable top to bottom and left to right. I would like it to be zoomed out and only scrollable top to bottom.

Here's the expected result for which I have to zoom out my browser window : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTUl2.jpg

Here's my current CSS:

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjiPU.jpg");

  width: 2880px;
  height: 3800px; 

  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I display that element using simply this in my body

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

I am sure the solution to this is extremely simple but after lots of research and being unable to start HTML from scratch, I'm asking if it's possible to simply display it in full width, scrollable top to bottom.

Here's the full code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {

}

.bg {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjiPU.jpg");

  width: 2880px;
  height: 3800px; 

  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please replicate your Problem here  in a code snippet. From your image i cannot understand which is your current result.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my OP with the full code if you want to replicate it. I've also added my expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to set your `bg`'s width to `100vw` -- that is, 100% of the viewport width and then set the `background-size` to `contain` and `background-position` to `top center`. You may need to adjust the height value.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/GAxG97r.jpg");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3800px; 
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm, just need to set the correct height. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped, but I would recommend looking at @kewwwa's answer as well. That's probably a cleaner solution if you're able to display your image inline with an `img` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible for you to use an "img" tag to display your image ?
Doing so, you simply need to set it's width to 100% (with CSS or width attribute).
The height will adapt to maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: I think that's also a solution, I'll look into that